# Boolean fields configuration - How to enter a string in ON/OFF value bigger than allowed?

Tags: entities

How to enter a bigger string than allowed in boolean fields?

When I try to submit a string bigger than a certain value, the string is automatically cutted.

I want to put this text:

> (4% du montant total de la location et 0.5 .- par jour et par personne pour l’assistance/rapatriement en cas de location à l’étranger)

But only this is allowed:

> (4% du montant total de la location et 0.5 .- par jour et par personne pour l’assistance/rapatriement en cas de location à l’étr

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Trim the field down to something suitable so it makes sense, something like - 4% du montant total de la location et 0.5, and put the rest into the description field.